# Ionic 2 use AngularFire2 list into the ts file

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

How can I use in AngularFire2 reference in ts file in ionic 2? (e.g. I have reference to my Firebase)

```
   this.courses=this.af.database.list('/CoursesList/2017/Software/A/SemA');
```

I want to check iterate in ts file (not in HTML file) and to do something with that data. Is it possible?

I tried to do that but i get error
[image]

this is my code

```
  this.courses
  .subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.val());


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! There's multiple ways of doing so. Calling `.list()` returns a `FirebaseListObservable` which is just an `Observable` with some convenient methods like `.push()`, `.set()`, `.update()`, and `.delete()`.

The most simple way is to call `.subscribe()` and iterate over the actual array.

```
af.database.list('/songs').subscribe(songs => {
  // songs is the downloaded array
  // type could simply be any[] or whatever model you need
  this.songs = songs;
  // or you can forEach or whatnot
  this.songs.forEach(song => console.log(song));
});
```

The more favorable way is to use an `Observable` operator like `.map()`:

```
af.database.list('/songs')
// Almost like a regular array map, but it emits for each item
// added over time
.map(song => {
  song.name = song.name.toUpperCase();
  return song;
})
.subscribe(songs => {
  // songs is the downloaded array
  this.songs = songs;
  // All the names will be in caps
  this.songs.forEach(song => console.log(song.name));
});
```

Make sure you import the `.map()` operator though or it won't work!

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map`
```

Comment: great explanation! I edited my post, can you see why is wrong?

Comment: Yes AngularFire unwraps the snapshot by default, so there's no need to call `.val()`. The parameter name shouldn't be `snapshots` because it's the actual POJO, not the`DataSnapshot`

Comment: here  // songs is the downloaded array
  this.songs = songs; , what type the downloaded array? how to declare it?

Comment: Check my updated comment. It's just an array `any[]` or your model

Comment: hey david, i still don't understand what wrong with my code, can you repair mine?

Comment: See my previous comments about the snapshots. Your code is improperly referencing them when they do not exist in subscribe. It's just a array of POJOs: `any[]`

Comment: Great it works for me! I have more some question about Angularfire, can i edit this post or to post new one?

Comment: It's best to create new questions rather than edit the existing one.

Comment: hey dear david, can you check  my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507265/angularfire2-how-to-make-auth-in-angularfire2-if-i-have-already-did-it-in-fireb